# Debugging asm in Visual Studio 2010: Can we take multiple steps like in GDB?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, .net-assembly, visual-studio-debugging

In gdb, I can type

```
stepi 100
```

To step 100 machine instructions forward.

Is there an equivalent in the Visual Studio Debugger?
The command 'p' in the Command window will "Step Over', and the command 't' will "Step Into" per the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx).

So of course, I tried:

```
p 100
100 p
```

But I just get:

> Command "Debug.StepOver" does not accept arguments or switches.

Does anyone know how to replicate gdb's behavior in the VS 2010 debugger?

Comment: I've never tried to use Visual Studio's debugger from a command line, but if you don't mind doing it in the window, there is something better than "stepi 100". If you right click on a line in your code, you can select "Run to cursor" to execute up until that line.

Comment: Oh, I know about that, but thank you. The problem is that I'm debugging asm without source, and I cannot figure out the structure of the asm a priori to take advantage of Run To Cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own Macro command that accepts a command line parameter.  Then you can use DTE.ExecuteCommand("p") to execute the p command in a loop.  Of course this is not the fastest approach, but it should work.